# Syslog still receiving entries after filter to sepaqrate file

Tags: 12.04, server, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to get remote devices to into separate log files and not in the main syslog file.

I have created a filter for remote devices to go to a separate file per host, but still remote devices log contents end up in main syslog. I've tried both `& ~` and `& stop`.

Common problem but can't find a working answer. rsyslog 5.8.6 (Ubuntu 12 LTS)

`/etc/rsyslog.d/20-external.conf`:

```
$template PerHostLog,"/var/log/external/%HOSTNAME%.log"
if $fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1' then -?PerHostLog
#& ~
& stop
```

All other files are the same, except for changes to `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to enable remote logging.

My files per host do have contents, but they are also still coming into the main syslog file.

Whats the best way to adjust either configuration or filter to make sure they stay in the separate files, and not in the syslog file.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't suppose you've tried `&~` (no space) rather than `& ~`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put both conditions on separate lines:

    if $fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1' then -?PerHostLog
    if $fromhost-ip != '127.0.0.1' then stop

Answer (score 0):

If your filters working you could edit your /etc/rsyslog.conf to stop duplicates as per this thread:

https://serverfault.com/questions/711708/stop-crontab-from-filling-syslog-ubuntu-15-04/717244#717244

Comment: This is on the right track expect I don't know which facility external syslog messages come under.

Comment: This link shows you a list of syslog facilities as well as a method of monitoring the actual messages on your system to see what codes are in use https://www.fir3net.com/UNIX/Linux/how-to-determine-the-syslog-facility-using-tcpdump.html